# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION In Reverse For Loop Of A Vector In C++

Tags: c++, runtime-error, juce

I am trying to get the path of a ValueTree in JUCE to be used for opening files where the trees differ. When trying to reverse iterate through the vector (at the bottom of the code below) I get an error after it has finished running through the for loop.  The error is "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)". I assume this is because once the for loop has finished it needs to subtract 1 from 0 and this causes an exception. What can I do to avoid this error and use the code commented out to return a string?

edit: path is just a string. Also, using a signed value seems to cause an issue as i still reaches -1 and causes the same error

```
std::vector<juce::String> propertyPathList;
while (currentTree.isValid())
{
    if (currentTree.isValid() == false)
    {

        break;
    }
    auto currentName = currentTree.getType().toString();
    propertyPathList.push_back (currentName);
    currentTree = currentTree.getParent();
}
String path;
auto listSize = static_cast<unsigned> (propertyPathList.size() - 1);
for (unsigned i = listSize; propertyPathList.size() > i; --i)
{
    DBG (propertyPathList.at (i));
//        path += propertyPathList.at (i);
}
```

Comment: So are you planning to have the unsigned underflow, be the exit condition for the for loop at the bottom?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of path? I don't see it in your code except for the commented part.

Comment: A bad instruction exception would seem to indicate either a severe compiler bug (unlikely) or a jump to a bad address (likely). What is the disassembly for your for loop?

Comment: I've made a couple of edits to the original post to clarify a couple of things. I'm still relatively new to C++ so not fully sure how much disassembly would be best to show. Any suggestions?

Comment: Being new is the exact time to learn debugging 101: compile in debug mode, run in a debugger, get a backtrace from the point of failure, and figure out why that series of calls and parameters causes a crash.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very fragile:

```
auto listSize = static_cast<unsigned> (propertyPathList.size() - 1);
for (unsigned i = listSize; propertyPathList.size() > i; --i)
{
    DBG (propertyPathList.at (i));
//        path += propertyPathList.at (i);
}
```

First, `size()` returns an unsigned integer, so no need to cast it. If the list is empty, you get an overflow.

The thing is that your just want to browse this list in reverse, so write a reverse loop:

```
for (auto it = std::rbegin(propertyPathList); it != std::rend(propertyPathList); ++it)
{
    DBG (*it);
//        path += *it;
}
```